# Why does my Combine future logic work inside of a Button, but not inside of it's own function called by a Button?

Tags: ios, swift, combine

## Future won’t work the same in a button as it does in it’s own function

I have a button that updates my upcoming notifications using Combine and it works well enough, but for some reason when I, as closely as I can, copy the block inside the button to it’s own independent function, and use that function in a button, it doesn’t work.

This works

```swift
    Button("updatePendingView") {
        let future = futureUpcomingNotificationRequests()
    
        future
          .map() {
              notificationRequestsToDates(notificationRequests: $0)
          }
          .sink(receiveCompletion: {
                    print("Completed with,", $0)
                },
                receiveValue: {
                    print("Recieved \($0) as an array of Dates")
                    upcomingNotificationDates = $0
                })
          .store(in: &subscriptions)
    
    }
```

This does not work (it does not use the final closure to set the array which updates the `View`)

```swift
    @State var upcomingNotificationDates: [Date] = []
    @State var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    ...
    
    Button("updatePending with future function") {
        updateNotificationView(subscriptions: subscriptions) {
            upcomingNotificationDates = $0
        }
    }

    func updateNotificationView(subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable>, closure: @escaping ([Date]) -> ()) {
        var subscriptions = subscriptions
        let future = futureUpcomingNotificationRequests()
    
        future
            .map() {
                notificationRequestsToDates(notificationRequests: $0)
            }
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {
                print("Completed with,", $0)
            },
            receiveValue: {
                print("Recieved \($0) as an array of Dates")
                closure($0)
            })
            .store(in: &subscriptions)
    
    }
```

Here’s my future factory:

```swift
    func futureUpcomingNotificationRequests(notificationCenter: UNUserNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()) -> Future<[UNNotificationRequest], Never> {
        Future<[UNNotificationRequest], Never> { promise in
            print("Original")
            notificationCenter.getPendingNotificationRequests { requests in
                    promise(.success(requests))
            }
        }
    }
```

Here’s my function to convert `[UNNotificationReuqest]` to `[Date]` s

```swift
    func notificationRequestsToDates(notificationRequests: [UNNotificationRequest]) ->  [Date] {
        var arrayOfDates: [Date] = []
        for request in notificationRequests {
            let realTrigger = request.trigger as? UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
            arrayOfDates.append((realTrigger?.nextTriggerDate())!)
        }
    //    return notificationRequest.trigger as! UNCalendarNotificationTrigger
        return arrayOfDates
    }
```

Despite what’s in my `updateNotificationView` function’s body being almost identical to what is in the original button, it doesn’t update the `View`’s array.  I the future in the `updateNotificationView` function isn’t even initializing(?, starting?), and I’m not sure why.

Comment: This line `var subscriptions = subscriptions` is your problem. That local variable will be reallocated (causing the subscriber chain to be deallocated) as soon as the function returns (before the work is complete). If you use the struct property `subscriptions` you will leak subscribers. You should handle all of this in a model object that can have one subscriber set up. Your button would then trigger the button to request notifications and publish them in a `PassthroughSubject` Or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you pass `subscriptions` as an argument:

```
func updateNotificationView(subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable>, closure: @escaping ([Date]) -> ())
```

This two lines:

1. updateNotificationView(subscriptions: subscriptions)
2. var subscriptions = subscriptions

Will result in creation of a NEW set (after `.store(in: &subscriptions)`) which is released in the end of the scope (end of `updateNotificationView`).

To fix this issue you have two options:

1. Make `subscriptions` **inout** argument AND remove `var subscriptions = subscriptions`.
2. Just use View's `subscriptions` property without passing it as an argument.